# Objets has properties but still shows empty and length is also zero - mejs

Tags: javascript, wordpress, javascript-objects

I am trying to grab **players** object from **mejs** object.

When I try to output the value of **mejs.players** it shows an object of values but object itself truns up to be empty.

Code:

```
jQuery('document').ready( function($) {
console.log(mejs);
console.log(mejs.players);
console.log("Length : " + Object.keys(mejs.players).length);
});
```

Output

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `mejs.players` looks to be an `array`

Comment: It is an object when I check with `typeof`

Comment: `typeof []` returns "object". Try `Array.isArray(mejs.players)` and see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Array.from(mejs.players).length to create an array instance from players object and then you can iterate over the element of the array and also use length property

Comment: I tried this too but it comes to be an **empty** `array` and we can still see objects inside the newly created array. This is really a weird problem.